# ClickOnce with external EXE will not validate

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, clickonce, dynamics-crm

Here's a famous error I'm getting on VS 2010, using ClickOnce deployment. It works fine locally as well as with a setup deployment. The publishing is working fine.

Here's the error I receive when I try to install the application from the ClickOnce:
'Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly CrmSvcUtil.exe.'

I've tried the most popular solution (as well as all the other solution I found on internet) http://geekswithblogs.net/rakker/archive/2007/12/06/117449.aspx

I really don't know what to do. The CrmSvcUtil.exe is in my required files (added by itself... but if I remove it, the ClickOnce stops working at all)

Do you have any other idea of how to fix that? Or a workaround?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Is CrmSvcUtil.exe your main executable, or is it an additional executable in your application? It sounds like a change is being made to that file after the manifest has been created such that the file hash no longer matches (this can happen, for instance, if you sign your assembly after the manifest has been created).

Comment: It is an additional executable

Answer (score 0):

Do you have that exe added to your project? What is the build action (should be 'content') and what is 'copy to output directory' ? (should be 'copy always').

Is that executable signed?

Are you publishing with Visual Studio?

Are you re-signing with Mage or MageUI after it is initially published?